# React hook that runs AFTER the DOM updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

I have a React app where I am hiding/showing an element based on state, and want to do some  calculations on that DOM element after the state variable changes.

I've tried using `useLayoutEffect`, but this still runs *before* the DOM has updated, so my calculations aren't useful. Is my understanding of `useLayoutEffect` wrong? Am I using it incorrectly?

Here's what I have

```js
const myComponent = () => {

  const elem = useRef()
  const [isElemVisible, setIElemVisible] = useState(false)

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // I want this to run AFTER the element is added/removed from the DOM
    // Instead this is run before the element is actually modified in the DOM (but the ref itself has changed)

    elem.current.getBoundingClientRect() // do something with this object if it exists
  }, [elem.current])


  return (
   <div id="base-element">
    { isElemVisible && (
      <div id="element" ref={elem}></div>
    )}
   </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You have the wrong dependency - `isElementVisible` isn't used in the effect, but `elem.current` is. The linter will tell you this if you have it turned on. Hooks will run once at the start, but afterwards only when the dependencies change. So depending on the ref rather than the trigger state value will make the effect be triggered by it's cause.

Comment: Also, `const bbox = elem.current && elem.current.getBoundingClientRect()` since the value of current will be undefined when the element is removed.

Comment: Thanks. Technically correct on both counts. I omitted the existence check since it's not really helpful in this example.

Comment: When I add `elem.current` to the deps, the effect still runs before the DOM change. It seems like this is running like `componentWillUpdate` instead of `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: [useLayoutEffect()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) runs after DOM updates but before browser paints, so that you can alter something based on (for example) bounding box, which runs the function again before the user sees any changes. Since you are not doing anything particularly useful inside the effect, how do you even know when it runs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to pass a function as ref and do stuff in that function:

```
const myComponent = () => {

  // other component code

  const elemRef = useCallback((node) => {
    if (node !== null) {
      // do stuff here
    }
  }, [])


  return (
   <div id="base-element">
    { isElemVisible && (
      <div id="element" ref={elemRef}></div>
    )}
   </div>
  )
}
```

Check out this https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node

Comment: I think you might be on to something here

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution to this, is to manually check for state update in a `useEffect` hook:

```js
const myComponent = () => {

  const elem = useRef()
  const [isElemVisible, setIElemVisible] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
   if (isElemVisible) {
     // Assuming UI has updated:
     elem.current.getBoundingClientRect() // do something with this object
   }

  }, [isElemVisible])


  return (
   <div id="base-element">
    { isElemVisible && (
      <div id="element" ref={elem}></div>
    )}
   </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: According to your example, what exactly is supposed to update the component state?

Comment: I have a button that calls `setIsElemVisible`

Answer (score 1):

You almost did it right.

useRef.current will always point to the same object during a component lifeCycle and will be changed only explicitly(like elem.current = something on some render).

but you can inspect when isElemVisible will change, and fire callback after it happens:

```
const myComponent = () => {

  const elem = useRef()
  const [isElemVisible, setIElemVisible] = useState(false)

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if(isElemVisible)
      elem.current.getBoundingClientRect()
  }, [isElemVisible])


  return (
   <div id="base-element">
    { isElemVisible && (
      <div id="element" ref={elem}></div>
    )}
   </div>
  )
}
```